# Intellij Idea can't find class files from other source

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, libgdx

I added a module to my project and marked its source file as a source. It does not show any errors in code by when I compile and run it it can't finds other module's class files

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nabu.bloodworks.models.PlayerPosModel

Problem is it does not add path of .class files to class path. Why this happens? When I google it all I get is "mark src as source folder" and I already did that.

[image]

I am trying to use "Bloodworks" module both in my server and client. Server is a simple java server and it works as intended, can see and import bloodworks but client can't see it. Client is a libgdx application and I am trying to run desktop module. As you can see bloodworks/src is marked as blue and I added it to dependincies, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should check export (for your module).

Otherwise desktop project won't be able to access that module after building.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, it is too late to answer, but I had to follow a different approach for this error to resolve this issue. Simply exporting the jar or library didn't work for me.

I had to create this as global library and add that library to the module, then only the error is resolved. I didn't have to export this.

[image: Add this as a global library]

[image: Then add that library as dependency to the project]